# resolve modules in testcafe typescript tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I encountered the module resolving issue in my testcafe(1.17.1) test.
I have a test

```
//test.e2e.ts in <root>/tests folder
import {MyComponent} from '../src/MyComponent';
...
...
fixture('Custom domain tests');

test('test 1', async () => {
  ...
  ...
});
```

the `<root>/src/MyComponent.tsx` looks like this

```
//MyComponent.tsx in <root>/src folder
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import styles from '../scss/MyComponent.module.scss';

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {
  ...
  ...
}
```

When I run `testcafe ./tests/test.e2e.ts`, I always got the error
`Error: TypeScript compilation failed. Cannot find module '../scss/MyComponent.module.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.` 
My testcafe tsconfig specified the path config, the `<root>/scss-module-for-tests.ts` just exports a empty string

```
// .testcaferc.json in <root>/
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typescript": {
      "options": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "../scss/MyComponent.module.scss": ["scss-module-for-tests.ts"],
          "*.scss": ["scss-module-for-tests.ts"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, seems typescript path config doesn't resolve relative path nor accept a regex, but My project has a lot of those `../scss/*module.scss` imports. Is there anyway to resolve the scss file directly for testcafe?

Thanks in advance!

Update on 12/02/2021
I tried add compiler for testcafe according to this [doc](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#compileroptions) , I put a `.testcaferc.json` at the root folder

```
//.testcaferc.json at <root>
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typescript": {
      "options": {
        "esModuleInterop": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But seems the `esModuleInterop=true` config didn't reach to testcafe.

Update 12/13/2021:
Not easy to configure it correctly, I removed the `*.scss` file reference in the test code. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your TestCafe tests' code references your testing application code. However, TestCafe tests do not require testing application code. In fact, the code of the TestCafe tests and the application can be divided into two separate projects. Please try to separate your web application code and your TestCafe tests' code.

Comment: Thank you @aleks-pro, true, my tests code refers the application code, I will split and refactor them. However, there are so many of such application code reference, I hope I can configure testcafe to make it work as first step.

Comment: Tried to add a `.testcaferc.json` for typescript compiler options, but testcafe seems ignore my config

Comment: It's hard to find the cause of the issue without a sample. Could you please share a project example where we can reproduce the issue? You can remove all sensitive data from it.